# Term for when someone says they'll show up to an event

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term used for when someone says they'll show up to an event?

The closest word I can think of is RSVP.

Comment: Strictly speaking, RSVP means a request to indicate whether one will attend or not. If you verbify it, it can either mean to request that response, or, if you want, to _send_ that response. The response, however, can also be "nopes, I'm not coming", so it doesn't mean one will attend. I am aware that RSVP has been abused of late to mean something like "the response that indicates my presence", but that is a rather informal use that will even draw negative attention from those who do not consider themselves pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

This link [*confirmation of attendance*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lunch%20date%20with%20friends%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22confirmation%20of%20attendance%20%22) confirms the term.

*reply to RSVP* is another.

RSVP is the request to reply/confirm, but I've seen "they sent back their RSVPs" which is decidedly informal though.

Comment: These suggestions are quite formal and cannot be used casually in cases "*... when someone says they'll show up to an event*".

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for, I suspect, is "estimated time of arrival" or "ETA," which refers to the approximate time when someone plans to show up at a specified event.

Comment: Seems like this answer takes the *when* literally in "when someone says they'll show up to an event."